# How to Make an Non-Database Auto-Attribute to a Django Model Instance

Tags: python, django, django-models

Sometimes, we save some fields that change a lot to Redis or other backends.

But in that way, we could lose the convenience of getting a value from an instance by `article.count`.

We usually set a property function to a model, which performs the logic of querying the memory based database.

```
class WhatEver(models.Model):
    @property
    def some_field(self):
        return redis.hget('what-ever-%s' % self.id)

    def set_some_field(self, value):
        return redis.hset('what-ever-%s' % self.id, value)
```

Ugly, but useful.

But, it doesn't work all the time, as it's an intrusive way to bring us the ability.

Say, we want to get a user's visits,

We actually want to call `user.visits`,

But it's not good for a submodule to overwrite the base module, so we can only wrap it as a function `get_user_visits(user)` and again, not elegant.

Do we have a way to do this kind of tricks automatically and non-intrusively?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, no existing solutions could solve my needs.

I've implemented it and open sourced: [django-in-memory-models](https://github.com/oldcai/django-in-memory-models)

It can be installed by `pip install django-in-memory-models`

Answer (score 1):

For setting the value, you'll have to do it at an instance level. So either by creating a custom method in the model, or by careful use of signals you can get that done.

For fetching the results, you can decorate the return from the model using a custom manager and a [custom method on the manager](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/db/managers/#adding-extra-manager-methods).

```
from django.db import models

class RedisManager(models.Manager):
    def visits(self):
        results = []
        for obj in self.model.get_query_set().all():
            obj.visits = redis.hget('what-ever-%s' % obj.id)
            results.append(obj)
        return results

class SomeModelNeedsVisits(models.Model):
    objects = RedisManager()
    # your normal fields here

for obj in SomeModelNeedsVisits.objects.visits():
      print(obj.visits)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Is there a way to use the Django ORM mechanism, but not `overwrite` or `monkey patch` the modules? Would it be better to "fake" a model?

Comment: What I described to you is neither overwriting nor monkey patching. It is the way described in the documentation to enrich the ORM with custom functionality.

Comment: Yes, it is. But it needs to change the `objects` assigned in the Model class? As I know of, it is not able to call from an instance like `instance.visits`, unless overwrite or patch to the original module.